# Add custom parameters to a programm called by wofi

Tags: wayland, i3

I am using `wofi` on an `arch-linux` system with `swaywm`.

I want to use the Wofi `drun` menu to launch the Brave Browser. Sadly Brave doesn't support `wayland` by default so I have to add these parameters to make it work

```
--enable-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland
```

Is there a way to configure `wofi` to call

```
/usr/bin/brave --enable-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland
```

instead of just `/usr/bin/brave`?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a fix but sadly not how to call custom parameters with wofi. For sway if you want to enable software to run nativly on wayland you need to set these enviroment variables. This allows Brave to run fine without having to use parameters.

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland
export QT_WAYLAND_FORCE_DPI=physical
export QT_WAYLAND_DISABLE_WINDOWDECORATION=1
export ECORE_EVAS_ENGINE=wayland_egl
export ELM_ENGINE=wayland_egl
export SDL_VIDEODRIVER=wayland
export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1
export MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1
```

**NOTE:** You don't need all these Parameters just to run Brave but with these you will be able to run almost every software naively.